# AWS s3 CopyObject function parameters values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use copyObject function to copy a Json file from one s3 bucket to other s3 bucket.

Example: A file /accounts/abc.json in bucket credit-account has to be copied to another bucket named debit-account

I hardcoded the parameters to be

```
sourcebucket = “Credit-account”
Sourcekey = “/accounts/abc.json”
Target bucket = “debut-account”
Target key = “abc.txt”
```

Cooyobject is throwing error

> the specified key does not exist

Can you please suggest the possible reasons? or things to be verified?

Comment: Can you provide the aws cli command that you use?

Answer (score 0):

The source key's first URL part is the bucket. So your source key should be something like that:

```
Sourcekey = “Credit-account/accounts/abc.json”
```